# Insert self lookup records in single dml

Tags: apex

I have an object called product which has field called Parent Product which is a lookup to product (self lookup). Is there a way I can insert a parent record and populate parent product for child record in single dml statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert parent and child record for different objects in a single DML:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm

But the documentation states:

> Also, the related records created in a single call must have different sObject types.

Which means it is not possible for self-lookups.

Comment: The documentation isn't quite correct here. It is _technically_ possible for self-lookups, but the parent and child records need to be in separate trigger chunks. That'll mean having at least 200 parent records (in the list being inserted) before having any child records. Possible, but so impractical that it may as well be impossible.

Comment: After toying around with it some more, it's possible/practical using `upsert` and putting in a record of a different sobject in the `List<SObject>` in between the parent and child records (preferably one without any triggers/rollups, and where you only specify an Id). Still, probably not worth the trouble to just save a single DML statement (i.e. just use two separate `insert`s).

Comment: Definitely good to know how that works behind the scenes, thanks @Derek!